# Second celery task in chain executing before database updates from first task are completed

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a a chain of celery tasks and the second task needs to run, not just after the first task is complete, but after the database updates from the first task are complete. I've managed to get this working in my test by using a `while` loop to wait for the first chord in the chain to end but that seems wrong. I've tried other things like `transaction.on_commit` but that didn't work either. What's the right way to do this so that there isn't a race condition?

```
# My simple model
class TestModel(BaseModel):

    # The datetime the item occurred
    occurred_at = models.DateTimeField(null=False, blank=False, db_index=True)

    # A fake quantity
    quantity = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=20, 
        decimal_places=10, 
        null=True, 
        blank=True
    )


@shared_task
def race_condition_tester() -> None:
    
    zulu = dateTime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')

    workflow = chain(

        # This chord should asynchronously write a bunch of things to the database
        chord(
            generate_list_of_test_items.s(
                zulu=zulu,
            ),
            spawn_tasks_from_list_of_test_items_and_write_each_item_to_database.s(),
        ),

        # This should run after the chord, but also needs to run after the database
        # updates are complete
        test_if_items_are_in_database.s(
            zulu=zulu,
        ),

    )
    workflow.apply_async()
    return None

@shared_task
def generate_list_of_test_items(
        results=None,
        zulu: str = None,
) -> List:
    logger.info(f"generate_list_of_test_items: {zulu=}")
    task_param_lists = []
    for i in range(10):
        task_param_lists.append([i, zulu])
    return task_param_lists


@shared_task
def spawn_tasks_from_list_of_test_items_and_write_each_item_to_database(
        results=None,
) -> None:

    task_param_list = results[0]

    # I use a chord here to asynchronously write all the items to the db
    chord_task = chord(
        [write_item_to_db.si(
            i=task_params[0],
            zulu=task_params[1],
        ) for task_params in task_param_list],
        chord_finisher.s()
    )

    # Using this we get a resulting_sum of 36 which is incorrect
    # chord_task()

    # Using this we get a resulting_sum of 36 which is incorrect
    # chord_task.apply_async()

    # Using this we get a resulting_sum of 36 which is incorrect
    # chord_task.apply_async()
    # time.sleep(5)

    # Using this we get a resulting_sum of 36 which is incorrect
    # from django.db import transaction
    # transaction.on_commit(lambda: chord_task.apply_async())

    # This works... we get 45
    result = chord_task.apply_async()
    while not result.ready():
        time.sleep(1)
    return None


@shared_task
def chord_finisher(*args, **kwargs): # noqa
    """
    Just a simple task for the chord
    """
    return "OK"

@shared_task
def write_item_to_db(i, zulu):
    import time
    from apps.pw import logics

    logger.info(f"write_item_to_db: {i=}, {zulu=}")
    time.sleep(i)
    models.TestModel.objects.create(
        occurred_at=dateTime.strptime(
            zulu, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'
        ).replace(tzinfo=TimeZone.utc),
        quantity=Decimal(i),
    )
    return None


@shared_task
def test_if_items_are_in_database(
        results=None,
        zulu: str = None,
):
    from apps.pw import models
    from apps.pw import logics

    logger.info(f"test_if_items_are_in_database")
    activities = models.TestModel.objects.filter(
        occurred_at=dateTime.strptime(
            zulu, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'
        ).replace(tzinfo=TimeZone.utc)
    )
    resulting_sum = Decimal(0)
    for activity in activities:
        resulting_sum += activity.quantity

    # resulting_sum should be 45
    if resulting_sum != Decimal(45):
        logger.error(f"test_if_items_are_in_database: {resulting_sum=} but should be 45")
    else:
        logger.info(f"test_if_items_are_in_database: {resulting_sum=}")
    return None
```

Comment: First, firing a Celery task within another Celery task is a bad practice AFAIR - may lead to deadlock, so be aware of it. Something is confusing here, You're talking about `chain` in the question but you're using `chrod` which has a `group` in the first part - which should run concurrently and write to your database in parallel. What am I missing here?

Comment: Akaik, it's not bad to start tasks in another task... It's bad to call `get` inside a task. And yes, I'm running a chain of commands... Each one is a chord. That's because a chain of chords was the only way I could get each chord to start only after the previous chord finished.